# Cardinality of a set including fractions

Tags: limits, cardinals

[image: question]

Attempt:

Let $G = \{x > 0 : \lim_{n→∞} \mathsf{frac}((n!)x) = 0\} .$

For each $f ∈ 2^ω$,

define $x_{f} = \sum_{n\ge1} \frac{f(n)}{n!}$

Put $W=\{x_{f} :f∈2^ω\}$.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information not otherwise available in your post. [See here for why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: My edit was for a typo only.

Comment: $\displaystyle\tt frac$ usual notation is $\displaystyle\left\{\right\}$. For example, $\displaystyle\left\{6\right\} = 0,\quad \left\{5.3\right\} = 0.3,\quad \left\{-5.3\right\} = 0.7,\quad\left\{-6\right\} = 0,\ {\rm etc}, \ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $f:(\Bbb Z^+\to \{0,1\}$ let $x_f=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}f(m)/m!.$

If $f\ne g$ then $x_f\ne x_g.$ Proof: Consider $m_0=\min\{m:f(m)\ne g(m)\}$ and WLOG suppose $f(m_0)=1$ and $g(m_0)=0$. Then $m_0\ge 1$ so $x_f-x_g\ge \frac {1}{m_0!}-\sum_{m=1+m_0}^{\infty}\frac {1}{m!}>0.$

If $ n\in \Bbb Z^+$ then $$\text {frac}(n!x_f)=\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}n!f(m)/m!\le \sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}n!/m!<\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{(n+1)^{m-n}}=\frac 1 n.$$

Comment: By this we have proved W is a subset of G, right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly right.

Comment: Unrelated digression: For each $x\in [0,1]$ there is a unique sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}$ such that (i) each $x_n$ is a non-negative integer with $0\le x_n\le n-1$ and (ii) $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n/n!.$